# How can I remotely restart a Windows XP machine?

Tags: windows-xp, script, remote, reboot

I would like to restart a remote XP machine by executing a script on my Windows machine. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use **shutdown** command.

Example:

> shutdown \\REMOTEMACHINENAME /r /t:0

or

```
shutdown /m \\REMOTEMACHINENAME /r /t 0
```

where \\REMOTEMACHINENAME is name of remote computer.

For full description shutdown command, see 
[How To Use the Remote Shutdown Tool to Shut Down and Restart a Computer in Windows 2000](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317371/en-us)